# Does PowerShell has something like "echo off" and "echo on" trigger?

Tags: powershell, echo, write-host

cmd/batch file could turn on and turn off "echo".
So in PowerShell, I have a bunch of "write-host" output, I want somewhere to turn on / off write-host for debugging convenience.

Does PowerShell has such a function?

Answer (score 9):

The `Set-PSDebug` [cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849697.aspx) has `-Trace <int>` parameter that can be used to same effect as `echo on`.

Comment: Thanks! So the command is "Set-PSDebug -Off"

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you simply put

> | Out-Null

at the end of any line where privacy matters... it's more or less the same as putting...

> @

... at the beginning of any 'batch' line where you want output hidden from users.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Write-Verbose` instead of `Write-Host`, this will make your debugging data controlled by the variable `$VerbosePreference`. This variable has the same value set as `$ErrorActionPreference`, and the default is `SilentlyContinue`, which means that no verbose output is generated. You can set this to `Continue` and then have your verbose output visible.